# Proving object cannot be profinite without Stone topology

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, infinite-groups, profinite-groups

A profinite group $G$ arises as an inverse limit $G=\varprojlim G_\lambda$ of finite discrete groups $G_\lambda$. There is a nice property which states that a group $G$ is profinite if and only if it is a Stone topological group.

Now say I construct a new group $\Gamma$ out of two profinite groups $G_1,G_2$ and want to ask the question: Is $\Gamma$ profinite? Typically, constructing an inverse limit system whose inverse limit is isomorphic to $\Gamma$ is a lost cause. (This is a generalizing statement: In many cases you can construct an inverse limit system, but I've kept the "construction" of $\Gamma$ very vague for this reason.) Instead, we might try to show that the group $\Gamma$ has the Stone topology.

If we choose to work in a realm which does not admit, or hasn't yet been shown to admit, the profinite if Stone implication, then we cannot lean on the Stone topology to prove an object $\Lambda$ (notably, not a group) constructed from two profinite objects $A_1,A_2$ is also profinite. A concrete example of this situation is the disjoint union of profinite quandles: Even though the disjoint union has a Stone topology, we still do not know if a Stone topological quandle is profinite, and so cannot tell immediately if the disjoint union is a profinite quandle.

Is there a canonical way of proving that "something" cannot be presented as an inverse limit of an inverse system of finite discrete "things" without referencing the Stone topological iff profinite equivalence?

Edit: I proved today that the disjoint union of profinite quandles is profinite, so this example holds in spirit, but not technically.

Comment: I think that the vagueness of the construction of $\Gamma$ probably makes this too hard to answer in general. However, at least to prove that something is not a profinite space/group, you may consider necessary conditions and prove that they do not hold for $\Gamma$. For instance, you may ask if it is ever possible that $\mathbb{Z}$ is a profinite group; the answer is "no", since profinite groups are always finite or uncountable.

Comment: @nowras Unfortunately considerations like this won't work. I'm looking for arguments that demonstrate something is not an inverse limit of finite discrete things, in particular, not things that follow from that. I'm working in a realm where most things are uncountable, very complex (infinite quandle structure), and I have no way to translate between Stone topology and profiniteness.

Comment: What is meant by the disjoint union of quandles?

Comment: Also, I want to point out that the Stone iff profinite equivalence has an "easy direction" and a "hard direction". The "easy direction" is that every profinite thing admits a Stone topological structure. This holds for all varieties of algebras. Now you ask "Is there a canonical way of proving that "something" **cannot** be presented as an inverse limit of an inverse system of finite discrete "things"?" By the contrapositive of the "easy direction", it suffices to show that you thing does not admit a Stone topological structure.

Comment: @AlexKruckman The disjoint union $Q\sqcup S$ consists of elements of $Q$ and elements of $S$ with the operation defined to be that of $Q$ or $S$, when appropriate, and if $q\in Q$ and $s\in S$, then $q\triangleleft s=q$. I've constructed an explicit inverse limit system for the disjoint union of profinite quandles.

Comment: @AlexKruckman By the way, I've looked at Johnstone's *Stone Spaces* and the argument for why the Stone/profinite equivalence follows for finitary algebraic categories with complete word sets. If you know about this proof, do you have a sense of how restrictive the argument is? Essentially what I mean is do you know of any theories for which we do have the Stone/profinite equivalence which do not admit a complete word set?

Comment: @AlexByard I'm aware of the result, but I don't know any examples of the kind you're looking for. You could ask this as a separate question - here, or on MathOverflow.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Just as a sort of meta question, where would I find better answers to such a question?